# Camunda use separate user for database creation scripts

Tags: database-migration, camunda

In my Camunda Spring Boot application I use `application.properties` to set database connection information, i.e

```
spring.datasource.url=<database url>
spring.datasource.username=<app username>
spring.datasource.password=<password>
spring.datasource.driverClassName=<driver>
```

When I first run it against an empty database Camunda is reusing this user information in order to run its database creation scripts. Is there the possibility to specify a separate database user for Camunda sql scripts? I would like to have 2 database users one for application and one for database migration tasks.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to have 2 database users, you should define properties of all 2 datasources in application.yml then you should create CamundaConfiguration  class to config camnuda datasource in spring boot.

insert below code into application.yml

```
datasource:
    initialize: false
    type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
    jdbcUrl: jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.0.1:1521:MYDB
    username: MYAPP
    password: MYAPP


camunda.bpm:
        job-execution-enabled:  true
        history-level: FULL
        auto-deployment-enabled: true
        id-generator: strong
        checkProcessDefinitions: true
        deployment-resource-pattern:  classpath:/process/**/*.bpmn
        datasource:
          type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
          schema-update: true
          schema-name: camunda
          jdbcUrl: jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.0.1:1521:MYDB
          username: camunda
          password: camunda
```

create CamundaConfiguration class

```
 package org.valz.service.impl;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.sql.SQLException;

 import javax.naming.NamingException;
 import javax.sql.DataSource;

 import org.valz.framework.common.core.Constants;
 import org.camunda.bpm.engine.spring.ProcessEngineFactoryBean;
 import org.camunda.bpm.engine.spring.SpringProcessEngineConfiguration;
 import org.camunda.bpm.engine.spring.SpringProcessEngineServicesConfiguration;
 import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
 import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
 import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
 import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
 import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
 import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
 import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
 import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;
 import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
 import org.springframework.core.io.support.ResourcePatternResolver;
 import org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor;
 import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager;
 import org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate;
 import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
 @Configuration
 @Import( SpringProcessEngineServicesConfiguration.class )
 public class CamundaConfiguration  {
     @Value("${spring.camunda.bpm.history-level}")
     private String historyLevel;

     // add more configuration here
     // ---------------------------

     // configure data source via application.properties

     @Autowired
     private ResourcePatternResolver resourceLoader;

     @Bean
     // @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.camunda.bpm")
     public SpringProcessEngineConfiguration processEngineConfiguration() throws IOException {
         SpringProcessEngineConfiguration config = new SpringProcessEngineConfiguration();

         config.setDataSource(camundaDataSource());
         config.setDatabaseSchemaUpdate("true");

         config.setTransactionManager(transactionManager());
         config.setHistory(historyLevel);

         config.setJobExecutorActivate(false);
         config.setMetricsEnabled(false);
         config.setJdbcBatchProcessing(false);
         // deploy all processes from folder 'processes'classpath:/process/*.bpmn
         Resource[] resources = resourceLoader.getResources("classpath:/process/**/*.bpmn");
         config.setDeploymentResources(resources);

         return config;
     }

     @Bean
     public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
         return new DataSourceTransactionManager(camundaDataSource());
     }

     @Bean(name="camundaBpmDataSource")
     @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.camunda.bpm.dataSource")
     @Profile(Constants.SPRING_PROFILE_DEVELOPMENT)
     public DataSource camundaDataSource() {
         System.out.println("spring.camunda.bpm.dataSource");
         return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
     }
     @Bean(name = "camundaBpmDataSource")
     @Profile(Constants.SPRING_PROFILE_PRODUCTION)
     public DataSource jndiDataSource() throws SQLException, NamingException {
         JndiTemplate jndi = new JndiTemplate();
         DataSource dataSource = (DataSource) jndi.lookup("camunda");
         return dataSource;
     }
     @Bean
     public ProcessEngineFactoryBean processEngine() throws IOException {
         ProcessEngineFactoryBean factoryBean = new ProcessEngineFactoryBean();
         factoryBean.setProcessEngineConfiguration(processEngineConfiguration());
         return factoryBean;
     }

 }
```

and add this class too

```
package org.Valz.boot.config;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.JndiDataSourceLookup;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DatabaseConfiguration {
   public DatabaseConfiguration() {
   }

@Bean(
    name = {"dataSource"}
)
@Primary
@ConfigurationProperties(
    prefix = "spring.datasource"
)

public DataSource dataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}
```

}

Comment: unfortunately it uses the second database user, i.e. `camunda` for both schema creation and business process starting

Comment: i  edit my post and add    DatabaseConfiguration  class . add this class to your code.

Comment: This still doesn't answer the question to use different users for DDL & DML